# Order details are not inserted when creates new Order

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.3 and I'm trying to create a new order. When the order is created, the products that I've associated to the order don't appear.

If I check my new order on my MySQL database I'm able to see the order on table **ps_orders** but If I execute query to see the order details on **ps_order_detail** I'm getting an empty table...

Someone knows what is happening here?

Best Regards,

Comment: how do you create the order? show some code

Comment: Hi Sergii, thanks for your answer. I'm creating order from my frontend as always. Regards.

Comment: Hi, so, if I understood correctly, default installation, after completing purshasing process (all modules default too), you do not see products in order (neither back nor front) and no rows with this order id in ps_order_detail table? If not, describe please process more precisely, I'll check on my side

Comment: Yes. Using default installation after completing purchasing process, I'm not able to see products in order management (backoffice). Which .php file manages process to save the order and the order details?. Best Regards and thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've enabled Prestashop debug mode and I've seen that when prestashop tries to insert new **ps_order_details** row, was catching an exception because my **ps_order_details** table doesn't have **original_wholesale_price** column defined.

Thanks all!

Comment: Yes, I was installing PS with default configuration but after that, I was executing an .sql script with DB definition from an old PS installation.